# WinForm propertygrid Collection Editor Add/Remove buttons Inactive

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid, collectioneditor

I am using the generic propertygrid to edit values from several custom classes.  Some of these classes have collections and I can open those collections without a problem in the Collection Editor without a problem. If the collection already contains objects I am able to select those objects and edit them on the right, but the the Add/Remove buttons are inactive.

I know for some of these collections are going to need a custom editor as they are quite complicated-- but most of them are quite simple. Is there an easy way active the add/remove buttons for these simple classes or do I need to create a custom editor for every collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Add and Remove button to be enabled, you need the collection to implement the non generic [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.collections.ilist%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) interface, and, obviously, the property [ReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.collections.ilist.isreadonly%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) must return `false`.

Note you need an explicit implementation on the class, just deriving from a class or interface that itself derives from IList (suc as `IList<Something>`) will **not** work.

For example, the following is not ok:

```
public class MyStuffCollection : List<MyStuff>
{
}
```

and the following is ok:

```
public class MyStuffCollection : List<MyStuff>, IList
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure what you mean by `explicit implementation on the class` -- Are you saying I have to build my own class, or are there classes in .NET the explicitly implement it?

Comment: It means your class must derive directly from `IList`. Deriving from a class or interface that itself derives from `IList` is not enough.

Comment: Since it needs to be derived from IList, does that mean that I will be unable to use anything like a SortedList or Dictionary?

Comment: No, you just have to implement IList (you can defer most methods implementation to an existing member class, or to the class you derive from).

Comment: I'm sorry for being dense, I can usually follow all this stuff. Is there anyway you could post an example of how I can implement a dictionary style collection `<key, value>` using 'IList` or link to an example/help page.