# Getting the PropertyGrid CollectionEditor to work with Generic Sorted Lists

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid, sortedlist, collectioneditor

I have a C# Library project that is used just for data structures; some of the classes use `SortedList` like this:

`SortedList<CustomItem1, CustomItem2> MySortedList;`

I then have a separate Windows Forms project using that uses a `PropertyGrid` to edit the data structures.  Everything works great for editing except for the `CollectionEditor`; the add/remove buttons are disabled. I understand that I need to implement the non-generic version of either ICollection or IList (I am finding mixed answers on that) - but to do so will break much of my code that relies on some of the methods that are unique to the  `SortedList` type.

Also, I would like to keep my Data Structures as small as possible and don't want the library to be dependent on anything from WinForms if possible.

Any ideas, references to related questions or help articles, examples, etc.. on how to activate the Add/Remove buttons in the CollectionEditor for a SortedList would be appreciated.

Comment: What was not clear enough in the question you deleted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167443/winform-propertygrid-collection-editor-add-remove-buttons-inactive ?

Comment: The question wasn't getting the correct answer, or at least not in a form I could understand. The answer you gave seemed to indicated I had to created my own custom collection class that wouldn't have any of the properties of a `SortedList` that I need. I felt that it was probably due to me not asking the question correctly so I deleted it so I could start over and hopefully ask the questions correctly this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MSDN documentation for [CollectionEditor Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.collectioneditor.aspx) states:

> This editor can edit collections that have an Item property. The
>   editor can determine the type of the collection from the **Item**
>   property, if it exists. If the collection does not have this property,
>   or if you want to provide collections of more than one type, **you can
>   override certain protected members of this class to customize the
>   editor to support other types of collections**.

Additionally the [Collection Editor Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zky1t4k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) document states:

> If you use a strongly typed IList implementation for your collection
>   property, and all the objects in the collection are of the same type,
>   you do not need a custom collection editor. In that case, you can rely
>   on the built-in CollectionEditor as the property editor because
>   CollectionEditor infers the object type from the type of the Items
>   property of the IList implementation. You should use a typed
>   collection whenever possible. **However, if you use a collection such as
>   ArrayList as the type of a controls' collection property, you need a
>   custom collection editor to specify the collection items' object type**.

So I don't think the CollectionEditor will work (out of the box) with your OrderedList.

Have you tried projecting your OrderedList collection into an IList collection?

```
IList<CustomItem2> myList = mySortedList.Select(m => m.Value>).ToList();
// Or
IList<KeyValuePair<CustomItem1, CustomItem2>> myList = mySortedList.Select(m => m).ToList();
```

Comment: I've thought about that -- but I don't believe that will allow for 2-way communication; i.e. changes I make won't be saved... Also, I wouldn't have anyway of updating the key, at least not that I can think of.

Comment: The projection will create new references to your existing object instances in a list. Changes the CollectionEditor makes to these object's state are effecting the same objects referenced by your SortedList collection (unless it creates new objects). Alternatively you could create a proxy object that encapsulates your SortedList collection, implements the IList interface and translates IList calls to corresponding SortedList calls. But if you were going to go to this much trouble I would just follow the API directions and "override certain protected members" of the CollectionEditor class.